# pd.DataFrame is overwriting columns, instead of saving data to pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, opencv, tracking

## Here, I am attempting to create a dataframe to compare the location of an object between frames:

```
Pcount = []
Pcountdb = []
framenumber = 0
frames_count = 0
frames_count = self.vdo.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(int(frames_count))) 
if len(outputs) > 0:
    for i in range(len(outputs):
        bbox_xyxy = outputs[:,:4]
        identities = outputs[:,-1]
        sx = outputs[:,0]
        sy = outputs[:,1]
        ex = outputs[:,2]
        ey = outputs[:,3]
        cx = ((sx + ex) /2)
        cy = ((sy + ey) /2)
        ct = (cx, cy)
        cx2 = (cx.tolist())
        cy2 = (cy.tolist())
        P = identities[i]
        df[str(P.astype(int))] = ""                              
        #creates new column with an id number obtained through deepsort

        df.at[int(framenumber), str(P.astype(int))] = [cx2[i], cy2[i]]  
        #the i function from a for loop is necessary for multiple objects in the same frame
        
        print(df)

        if not P in Pcountdb:
            global PcountT
            Pcountdb.append(P)
            PcountT = PcountT + 1

framenumber = framenumber + 1
```

Edited: The script above starts with placeholders

df = pd.DataFrame... creates my dataframe with a row for each image/frame in my video

bbox_xyxy is created once my object detector has been looped over by deepsort, and deepsort has identified each detected object and identified it as an object with a location.

I then, break apart the np.arrays and calculate the center points of these objects so they can be seen as an individual point, instead of a bounding box rectangle.

Pandas takes my inputs and creates a DataFrame with the object id (in this case, 1), the center x y coordinates and places them in the row corresponding with each frame

## next, we print the dataframe and view the results

## print(df) returns:

```
                     1
Frames                
3       [614.5, 632.0]

                     1
Frames                
3                     
4       [610.5, 624.0]

                     1
Frames                
3                     
4                     
5       [603.0, 618.0]

                     1
Frames                
3                     
4                     
5                     
6       [574.0, 615.5]

                     1
Frames                
3                     
4                     
5                     
6                     
7       [564.0, 610.0]

                     1
Frames                
3                     
4                     
5                     
6                     
7                     
8       [559.0, 597.0]
```

The DataFrame keeps track of ONLY the most recent set of coordinates per column.  If I were to produce two columns, only the last sighting of each object will be present in my dataframe (as shown above with one object, identified as 1)

## I need to save the output to my pd.DataFrame = df, instead of being overwritten.

```
                     1
Frames                
3       [614.5, 632.0]
4       [610.5, 624.0]
5       [603.0, 618.0]
6       [574.0, 615.5]
7       [564.0, 610.0]
8       [559.0, 597.0]
```

So I can compare locations of these objects between frames, giving me an object count that counts objects and stores them in 2 databases, "UP and "DOWN"

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: Can you mention clearly what it is you want as output?

Comment: Apologies, I would like this data to be saved to my pandas.DataFrame = df so i can access it further down the script.

Comment: why you are using .at. do you want to store it at a specific location?

Comment: If there is another way to graph my coordinates to these locations, please share !

Comment: Because my data needs to correspond with the current frame where the detection takes place, and the column that I have created from my new outputs.  (outputs) is an np.array that holds the coordinates and an ID# for my column.  I am open to any sort of suggestion, I am not attached to using .at but it seemed like most logical function to use in this situation.

Comment: kindly elaborate more. like what contains in P,frame_count,framenumber.  because here I see framenumber is not iterated

Answer (score 1):

Your DataFrame is just adding last raw because every time for loop runs you're resetting column to null. so all previous values are erased.
by looking at your code I can see that as your code doesn't require to be in for loop.

**solution**:

```
Pcount = []
Pcountdb = []
framenumber = 0
frames_count = 0
frames_count = self.vdo.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(int(frames_count))) 
if len(outputs) > 0:
    bbox_xyxy = outputs[:,:4]
    identities = outputs[:,-1]
    sx = outputs[:,0]
    sy = outputs[:,1]
    ex = outputs[:,2]
    ey = outputs[:,3]
    cx = ((sx + ex) /2)
    cy = ((sy + ey) /2)
    ct = (cx, cy)
    cx2 = (cx.tolist())
    cy2 = (cy.tolist())
    P = identities[i]
    df[str(P.astype(int))] = ""
    for i in range(len(outputs):
        df.at[int(framenumber), str(P.astype(int))] = [cx2[i], cy2[i]]
        print(df)
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried, but had to move P=identities[i] and df[str(P.astype(int))] = "" to the for i in range (because P relies on i).  I am looking for a workaround or another way to merge the data of this dataframe to another.  I have attempted to use pd.concat to join this dataframe to an identical copy of this dataframe: df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=range(int(frames_count))) my result was: df2 creates the column for the object but didn't append the coordinates so my dataframe was empty

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(outputs)):
                    P = identities[i]

                    if not P in Pcountdb:
                        df[str(P.astype(int))] = ""
                        global PcountT
                        Pcountdb.append(P)
                        PcountT = PcountT + 1
                    else:
                        if P in Pcountdb:
                            df.at[int(framenumber), str(P.astype(int))] = [cx2[i], cy2[i]]


[222 rows x 1 columns]
                     1
 Frames                
 4       [610.5, 624.0]
 5       [603.0, 618.0]
 6       [574.0, 615.5]
 7       [564.0, 610.0]
 8       [559.0, 597.0]
 ...                ...
 226     [640.5, 518.5]
 227     [643.0, 525.0]
 228     [646.0, 529.5]
 229     [647.5, 529.5]
 230     [650.5, 531.5]
```

Thank you @Adarsh for your response, you were right, my columns were being overwritten because i was creating them from a loop.

I took the line df[str(P.astype(int))] = "", where columns are created and ran it with an exclusive circumstance.

Comment: 'https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/08/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/'

Comment: thanks! however, my level is too low to upvote on the page, but you got mine !